# Mongodb atlas setup with mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb

The connection shows an error but connects when I stop the Windows security firewall.
Is it safe to stop the security firewall for setup?

What should I do?  I tried all the methods like adding an IP address, but still, it shows an error.

Comment: can you provide the error message